# How can I send HTML data to PHP using JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I can't seem to understand how to send data from my **Client-side HTML** to my **Server-side PHP** (Which already means their not in the same folder and are not running in the server) and only get a Notice of an unidentified variable and a Fatal error: Cannot access empty property.

I tried the methods in W3Schools and still no luck. And just to be sure I tried to copy paste it. Still the same.

So my question is: How can I send this simple Client-side HTML/JavaScript data:-

```
<script>
function sender(){
obj = "tblname";
// how to send that data to the php server-side.
}
</script>
```

To this PHP:-

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], false);

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "mydb");
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM ".$objData);
$outp = array();
$outp = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($outp);
?>
```

Using JSON?

If anyone could elaborate and show me a sample it would be great.

Again, I am a noob/newb in using JSON and have no long term background (I just started like a week ago and that had a lot of problems already) and am completely clueless when it comes to this type of client-to-server communication.

**I Just need the simple sender code (from the JavaScript) and the receiving code (from the Php) one or two lines will do; with a short description on how they work.**

I'm using Windows 7, Wamp3.0.6 and Chrome.

PS: I got that from W3Schools. Yes it didn't work. And please don't be Vague. Thank you!

Comment: Wait back up a little. Where did the variable `obj = "tblname";` come from? Is it from a HTML form? Do you mind if the page refreshes? Or do you want to send the data via AJAX? JSON doesn't really come into this as you're just sending a string...

Comment: No not fine when the page refreshes coz that could result loss of short term data. I'm fine with AJAX as long as it's explained.

Comment: Or post up your JS attempt and someone will help you out.

Comment: last time i tried it, never got a working answer. And @charlietfl , if you already read the problem, you might understand that it took me a week; a crazy eyebrow shedding week to get to that point in JSON and I can not spend another week trying to understand and ask more questions about AJAX. I just want to know how to send *that javascrpt data to my php* in an explained and simple way. I mean there are tones of ways to do this and you guys are supposed to be really good at this.

Comment: "I Just need the simple sender code", that is not how StackOverflow works! You need to show some effort yourself. There are many tutorials out there on AJAX go find some. We are not going to teach you AJAX, it is too broad. A top tip: the Jquery library has some excellent methods to help with AJAX, but it is not the only solution.

Comment: @Jon P I already answered my question. Just read it. And I just wanted to send a string and not an entire lesson about something new to me like AJAX. I'm still on JSON. AJAX was supposed to be my next criteria of learning coding. So, sometimes you people make me wonder if you really read my question... And don't worry, your method of discouraging me into asking questions here in StackOverflow worked. Thanks. And by the way I did try to learn how to but understanding "vague" is not one of my strong suits.

Comment: You can't send anything via JSON as it is purely a data format. It would be the same as trying to send something via XML. You use AJAX to communicate from the browser/client to the server using JSON (or XML) to format data.

Comment: And I'm sorry if I came off rude. I was trying to explain that StackOverflow is not a "Code Factory". We don't respond well to questions that are along the lines of "Here is my problem, please write my code for me". Better questions are along the lines of, "Here is my code, this is how it is not working, please explain to me where I have gone wrong"

Comment: I wasn't expecting an entire running system of codes. I just wanted a sample of how it's done the right way coz of my server bugs. and i'm actually along the lines of the second thing you described. i satated codes. i stated the bugs. and then i stated i didn't know why it always had them. and i ended up creating an entire round about way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-_-
Everyone seems to try and over complicate and over think this when the *simple* answer would have been this code.

```
function caller(){
myData = "myTbl";
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "bring.php?q="+myData,true); //sends myData to the php. You can change the GET to POST if ya want to be extra safe but either way, the php won't care anyways.
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The above code is from the client server and sends the data of `myData` to this Server-side php.

```
<?php
$q = $_REQUEST['q']; //the receiver of the data. You can use explode() to separate them into pieces and turn it into a jigsaw puzzle if ya want.

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "Mydb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} // how to connect is not important in my question but it is important for you to be able to connect to the database.

// now for the important stuff

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$q." "; // I had to extend it with a space because sometimes it's misunderstood.
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($conn));
$outp = array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $outp[] = $row;
}
    echo json_encode($outp); //sends the data gathered from the database table back to the client as a JSON file, and you are done.
?>
```

It took me 6 hours worth of studying with a lot of internet surfing and trials and errors.

And like I said; I am a newb at JSON so it's pretty much understood that I don't understand AJAX. Like, AT ALL.

I'm sorry if ya think I sound like an idiot but let's face it, almost all of us were idiots at one point while trying to learn programming. So, I'm surprised why some people are just plain rude here. Thanks. Somehow I'm not really surprised that their also like this here. Makes my internet social life a bit more boring.

So next time, do me a favor and instead of being totally rude, just answer the question if you have one.

Comment: Just so you know, what you have here is a basic AJAX request. There are some interesting cross browser issues with AJAX so it is recommended to use a library to counter this. [Jquery](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/) is a popular option but it is not the only one. Also see https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-jquery-shorthand-ajax-methods/ and https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/

Comment: Actually, I tried researching it but i somehow always end up with some fatal errors. Tried the links you sent me too(actually before I even posted this question). And like it said in my question, I always end up with the two errors. I had to find out why it wouldn't work with those methods. That's why I asked. And this is only a partial of my code coz I had to use a couple more to have a round about way of doing it. I think it's something wrong with my WAMP server. Hell it won't even run if i don't have an internet connection. 0_0 yes i tried the Uni&Rei method. still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can make ajax call form client side to server file and can send data with get method

```
// Using the core $.ajax() method
$.ajax({

    // The URL for the request
    url: "path of your php file",

    // The data to send (will be converted to a query string)
    data: {
        id: 123
    },

    // Whether this is a POST or GET request
    type: "GET",

    // The type of data we expect back
    dataType : "json",
})
  // Code to run if the request succeeds (is done);
  // The response is passed to the function
  .done(function( json ) {
     })
  // Code to run if the request fails; the raw request and
  // status codes are passed to the function
  .fail(function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
    alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );

  })
  // Code to run regardless of success or failure;
  .always(function( xhr, status ) {
    alert( "The request is complete!" );
  })
```

Comment: note this requires jQuery as dependency...not mentioned

Comment: actually i already almost mastered the receive from php bit using json my problem is only the sending to php bit.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot transfer an object via HTTP as it is. You need to transform it into a string you can put into the body of your HTTP-POST Request:

```
try {
  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(anyJsonObject);
  //send it to the server
} catch(ex) {
  //handle error if anyJsonObject wasn't a valid JSON object. Remember: Not every JS object is a JSON object too.
}
```

The opposite way is:

```
try {
   var jsonObject = JSON.parse(anyJsonString);
} catch(ex) {
   //handle error if anyJsonString was malformed
}
```

Comment: i already know how to do that, it's not really an answer to my question

Comment: Oh and I answered my question. It'll help clear out the idea of your *"You cannot transfer an object via HTTP as it is"* part. You can use the `$_REQUEST` with some `xmlhttp` help.